# Write Opus Data to playable Opus File (Java)

Tags: java, audio, ogg, opus

I'm trying to write opus audio packets from a stream to a file using Java so that the file can be successfuly played (via VLC or what have you). I'm currently using the VorbisJava library to no available. Currently, I buffer all the received audio packets and then write the file once I know I am not going to receive any more audio. Here is my sample code so far:

```
    public static void writeWithLibrary(List<OpusAudioData> opusAudioData, OutputStream outputStream)
{
    OpusInfo opusInfo = new OpusInfo();
    opusInfo.setNumChannels(1);
    opusInfo.setOutputGain(0);
    opusInfo.setPreSkip(0);
    opusInfo.setSampleRate(48000);

    OpusTags opusTags = new OpusTags();

    OpusFile opusFile = new OpusFile(outputStream,opusInfo,opusTags);

    for (OpusAudioData o : opusAudioData)
    {
        opusFile.writeAudioData(o);
    }

    try
    {
        opusFile.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        logger.error("OpusFileWriter -- Could not write data to OpusFile, aborting");
    }

}
```

Any help would be  appreciated. Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: Not a good sign that this is so old, I just posted a similar thing on their site 
https://github.com/Gagravarr/VorbisJava/issues/39